# Closed Graph from a Collection of Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, 3d

Say I have two types of vertices:

- (D) vertices have two edges
- (T) vertices have three edges

Given a collection of these vertices, is there any way to prove whether they can be joined edge-to-edge to form a closed (i.e. no free edges) graph in 3-space?

For example, say I have 3 (T) vertices and 1 (D) vertex.  (Unless I've missed something obvious) there is no way to join these vertices into a closed graph in space, but I'm not able to come up with a proof.  On the other hand, 4 (T) vertices and 0 (D) vertices form a simple tetrahedron.

What about higher-order examples, such as 12 (T) vertices and 4 (D) vertices?  Ideally I would like to be able to construct an example of a graph in cases where they exist, at least for small collections like these, but this isn't tagged for `constructive-mathematics` because I don't consider construction an absolute requirement.

Comment: 3-space comes in because these graphs represent something in the real world, although I guess the question is mathematically equivalent to the 2-D case as long as you allow edges to cross. And by "free edge" I mean an edge that's only connected to a vertex at one end. I think that because of the way graphs and edges are defined your rephrasing is equivalent and would be a more standard way to think about the question. The real-world analog is what lead me to phrase the question in this slightly roundabout way.

Comment: @realityChemist : Oh, so 'free edge' is like what is called a 'flag' in some contexts. Actually, I un-retract my previous comment. Havel-Hakimi should give you what you want. Given a degree sequence like [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2] it gives you the connectivity of a graph if one can be constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Claim: A graph comprised of exactly $t$ vertices of degree $3$ and $d$ vertices of degree $2$ and no other vertices exists if and only if the following conditions are met:

- $t$ is even
- $t+d\geq 4$

or

- $t=0,d=3$

A sketch of an proof:

The condition that $t$ must be even is seen immediately from the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).  That $t=0,d=3$ works is seen from the example $K_3$.  That no other graphs with less than four vertices works is obvious.

What remains is to show that every other can be created.  We do this by induction.  $K_4$, $C_4$, and the diamond graph $K_4-e$ work as examples for base cases.

Given a graph with $t$ vertices of degree three and $d$ vertices of degree $2$, we may increase the number of vertices of degree $2$ by one by replacing any edge $\{u,v\}$ with two new edges and a vertex between them: $\{u,x\},\{x,v\}$, as pictured below:

[image]

becomes:

[image]

For increasing the number of vertices of degree $3$ by two, we may take any two distinct edges and replace them both like above with the additional step of connecting the two newly created vertices, as pictured below:

[image]

becomes

[image]

(*Note: we merely require the edges be distinct, but they may share a vertex if desired.  They cannot share two vertices since otherwise the edges would not have been distinct in the first place.*)

It should be clear that the newly created graphs using either of these modifications will be a graph with the desired number of vertices of degree $3$ and $2$ and the degrees of the vertices from the original graph are unchanged by the process.

It follows by induction then that every choice of $t,d$ possible where $t$ is even and $t+d\geq 4$ leads to the construction of a graph with $t$ vertices of degree $3$ and $d$ vertices of degree $2$ with no other vertices.

---

As an example of the ideas above being put into action, you ask about $d=4,t=12$.  The following graph was created using $C_4$ as a base, and repeatedly applying the modifications described in the induction argument.  (*you can even see exactly the order in which they were applied if you note how the vertices are labeled, since I just used the default names for the vertices as they were created*)

This is of course not the only example of a graph with $d=4$ and $t=12$ but it should hopefully highlight how such a construction could occur.

[image]

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the condition that the two edges in the induction step for increasing $t$ must not share any vertices is unnecessary.  Any choice of two distinct edges suffices.  As an aside, through careful wording, one can even show that not only can such a graph exist, but you can even show that such a graph can be both planar (*drawable in 2d with no crossing edges*) and connected as well.